# how is induced current is produced in an inductor when electric field inside an inductor is zero

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits

Electric field inside an inductor is zero. If that being the case, how is induced current produced in an inductor.? I am assuming some electric field has to be there for charges to be move and constitute current

Comment: Just like any other wire, the wire in a real inductor has non-zero resistance and therefore non-zero field within the wire. But we consider the case of the limit as R->0, since it makes the math easier.

Comment: Related: [Is the electric field zero inside an ideal conductor carrying a current?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28660/22927)

Answer (score 1):

" I am assuming some electric field has to be there for charges to be move and constitute current"

That's right. The usual assumption is that the inductor is stationary in our frame of reference, so the free charges in the wire of the inductor have to be in an *electric* field in order to experience a force urging them through the wire, and so giving rise to the emf.

The electric field arises, according to Faraday's law, from the changing magnetic field due to the current changing in the inductor, the electric field lines being closed loops surrounding the magnetic field lines.

So I think your claim: "Electric field inside an inductor is zero." is incorrect. There will be an electric field if the magnetic field is changing.

Comment: This is exactly right!

Answer (score 0):

You know that:
$$v=L \frac{di}{dt}$$
$$v=\int_{a}^{b}{\mathbf{E}\bullet \mathbf{ds}}$$
$$\int_{a}^{b}{\mathbf{E}\bullet \mathbf{ds}}=L \frac{di}{dt}$$
Now, I don't know why you say that eletric field inside the inductor must be zero (are you considering a particular case?). In this case, you must have a constant current flowing throw the inductor to satisfy the previous equation.